# Entire function , guidance or advice

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ entire and , $|f(z)|\le m\ e^{a\mathop{\rm Re} z}, z\in\mathbb{C},$ $a,m>0$

Show that $f(z)=Ae^{az}, A\in \mathbb{C}$

I think that most of these case are dealt with Liouville's Theorem , but I'm not familiar enough with these methods and I get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Find an entire function $g$ such that you can write the inequality as

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant m\lvert g(z)\rvert.$$

Apply Liouville's theorem to $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$.